# How do I use sinon stub a management client endpoint while using the Auth0 Management API node library?

Tags: auth0, sinon, stub

I have the following code to try and stub out the Auth0 Management API function...

```
import {ManagementClient} from 'auth0';
import sinon from "sinon";

const component = new Auth0App();
const getUsersInRoleStub = sinon.stub(ManagementClient.prototype, 'getUsersInRole');
getUsersInRoleStub.returns([
  {
    roles: ["rol_EOy9RkqdtAb1Jdde"]
  }
]);
```

I tried using the star syntax but it doesn't work and I am not sure if I am doing it correctly...

```
import * as auth0 from 'auth0';
import sinon from "sinon";

const component = new Auth0App();
const getUsersInRoleStub = sinon.stub(auth0.ManagementClient.prototype, 'getUsersInRole');
getUsersInRoleStub.returns([
  {
    roles: ["rol_EOy9RkqdtAb1Jdde"]
  }
]);
```

But that also doesn't work.

I also tried...

```
import * as auth0 from 'auth0';
import sinon from "sinon";

const component = new Auth0App();
const getUsersInRoleStub = sinon.stub(auth0, 'ManagementClient');
getUsersInRoleStub.returns({
  getUsersInRole: ()=>{
    return [
      {
        roles:["rol_EOy9RkqdtAb1Jdde"]
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

And got...

> TypeError: ES Modules cannot be stubbed

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by adding a setter to my class...

```
constructor(isTest = false) {
    if(!isTest){
      this.mc = new ManagementClient({
        domain,
        clientId: process.env.AUTH0_ADMIN_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_ADMIN_SECRET,
      });
    }
  }
  set managementClient(client){
    this.mc = client;
  }
```

And using this test code...

```
import {ManagementClient} from 'auth0';
import sinon from "sinon";

const component = new Auth0App(true);
const mc = sinon.createStubInstance(ManagementClient);
// const getUsersInRoleStub = sinon.stub(mc, 'getUsersInRole');
mc.getUsersInRole.callsFake((options, callback) => {
  // fake implementation
  callback(null, [
    {
      roles: ["rol_EOy9RkqdtAb1Jdde"]
    }
  ]);
});
component.managementClient = mc;
```